# Drawing many paths in single shape using Graphics2D Bezier Curve

Tags: java, awt, bezier

Please help me on how to draw a shape using Graphics2D libraries. 
That shape has a path which taken from .svg file.
How to draw same shape by java and display it on an awt JFrame? The path is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<path  d="m 422.25764,974.44618 
c 0.62138,-0.0746 1.75771,1.06129 2.36421,2.98433 0.0315,0.0766 -0.68474,0.41009                    
 -0.71114,0.46361 -0.6326,1.05467 -1.52406,1.83533 -2.77441,2.6392 -0.43509,-0.91104  -0.52393,-1.70072 -0.74833,-2.34191 -0.22902,-0.63165 -0.396,-1.06757 -0.39844,-1.44283 0,-0.33371 0.0997,-0.64158 0.45974,-1.16655 0.51629,-0.74482 1.31804,-1.13113 1.80835,-1.13585 z

 m -11.5102,6.90547 
c 0.0229,-8e-4 0.0412,-8e-4 0.062,0 0.73295,0.0149 1.65189,1.1421 2.29485,2.45383  -2.29545,0.51575 -3.9309,-0.30763 -3.96949,-0.8076 0.0101,-0.58284 0.91061,-1.60082 1.61259,-1.64623 z
 m 21.36555,2.05104 
c -1.86343,2.56739 -4.27572,3.04759 -6.5439,2.34948 -1.50641,-0.48472 -2.57444,-1.53726 -3.19873,-3.11172 1.64954,-1.39373 3.61989,-3.29628 3.92443,-4.71392 0.52453,-2.48987 -0.16567,-4.46323 -1.63761,-6.00404 -0.35259,-0.35247 -1.30924,-0.43838 -1.6946,-0.48474 -0.1445,-0.0174 -0.28454,-0.0175 -0.4291,0 -1.01192,0.12268 -2.8825,1.24733 -3.3388,2.25388 -1.0821,2.29486 -0.3907,5.39846 0.61719,7.66014 -1.49231,0.82723 -3.54904,1.68049 -5.07543,2.12491 -0.42938,-1.40319 -0.40783,-3.34993 -1.59908,-4.79196 -1.10233,-1.27046 -4.03902,-0.91215 -4.83829,0.13925 -1.84471,2.44015 -0.42587,6.12024 0.18454,7.0005 1.10044,1.43715 3.56705,1.14657 5.36503,0.77653 -4.24788,9.44304 -8.82131,9.07212 -14.99561,7.87582 -0.66344,-0.11985 -4.40582,1.34024 -3.93038,1.63229 3.08618,1.61186 10.21392,1.93 13.59247,0.27118 3.11258,-1.52841 6.11964,-5.0517 6.82676,-10.28314 2.23997,-0.70968 3.61646,-1.4293 5.34317,-2.34788 0.96569,2.59279 1.77306,4.25088 4.20863,5.00135 3.22983,0.93748 6.13624,-0.68258 7.55088,-2.89928 0.49523,-0.75937 0.68396,-0.86212 1.10163,-0.14973 1.57462,3.09971 6.01007,4.16902 9.97479,2.19814 3.53094,1.26362 6.0483,-0.0626 7.92272,-1.72344 0.66597,0.9248 3.51732,2.03386 4.25958,1.90197 0.77891,-0.16324 1.25413,-1.39941 2.0732,-3.05771 1.99421,0.92835 5.26838,1.89896 5.93368,1.59911 1.85777,-0.8827 1.14978,-5.75424 0.93422,-7.61268 -0.41355,-3.48893 -1.64863,-8.65527 -2.31934,-13.0189 0.39135,-0.51705 0.75416,-2.32899 0.96414,-2.88175 0.17001,-0.73891 -1.48785,-0.52761 -1.8962,-2.01039 -0.0315,-0.10994 -0.10857,-0.17231 -0.19636,-0.17573
 l -10e-5,6.8e-4    
 c -0.0877,-8.8e-4 -0.18678,0.053 -0.25997,0.17921 -0.35245,0.71415 -1.04154,1.7466  -1.22807,2.32933 -0.0546,0.15679 -0.038,0.26225 0.0253,0.40466 0.23266,0.49058 0.82733,1.44531 1.05249,1.93305 0.92658,5.88179 2.59257,14.07191 2.92942,16.8167 -0.55397,1.43149 -3.90406,0.16127 -4.93765,-0.19112 0.75112,-2.27612 -0.58221,-2.57166 -0.83417,-2.04915 -0.43621,0.98873 -0.47361,3.44977 -1.3941,4.58227 -0.11381,0.13924 -0.1691,0.16479 -0.32704,0.13609 -0.90655,-0.16515 -2.64734,-0.57452 -3.38522,-1.02327 0.31022,-0.58754 0.95892,-1.83649 1.02784,-2.6788 0.02,-0.86167 -1.32769,-0.59889 -1.54538,-0.0499 -1.15034,3.2856 -3.5553,4.6267 -6.91502,4.71419 1.14692,-1.54038 1.40236,-2.68829 1.54054,-4.17257 0.0651,-0.76121 -1.31386,-0.69932 -1.54602,-0.0283 -1.08257,2.53934 -1.55895,3.4161 -4.00178,3.9282 -2.2239,0.41552 -4.55677,0.0724 -6.91153,-2.45669 -0.97599,-1.17409 -1.67598,-0.77109 -2.37317,0.10785 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Batik SVG](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) library

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, but i want to draw it on JFrame instead of using Batik libraries. I really want to know how can i use relative path in Java Graphics2D, the curveTo method in GeneralPath class in Java Graphics2D works for absolute path only..
Helping Please
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for it,
First convert coordinates from relative coordinates to absolute coordinates that is from .svg file 
Open Inkscape software --> ctrl+shift+P -->Prefrences --> SVG Output --> Path data --> uncheck Allow relative coordinates and --> check Force repeat commands --> Iconify 
Then open the .svg file by notepad then get the coordinates from the source file and then substitute them in the java program

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class ZakCurve extends Frame {



          public static void main(String[] a){
              (new ZakCurve()).setVisible(true);
              GeneralPath g=new GeneralPath();
          }
          ZakCurve(){
              super("Test");
               setSize(500, 500);
               addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                   System.exit(0);
                 }
               });
             }


           @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
               Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
               g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

               GeneralPath path=new GeneralPath();

               path.moveTo(457.61616,470.82943 );                 
               path.curveTo(458.41016,425.70843 ,427.74316,392.55343 ,403.93516,370.91243 );
               path.curveTo(399.48516,366.83843 ,398.54916,368.02743 ,397.41516,372.27043 );
               path.curveTo(394.75116,382.25643 ,392.96616,392.69543 ,391.09516,402.03043 );
               path.curveTo(390.35916,405.62343 ,389.79116,406.92443 ,392.62616,409.52743 );
               path.curveTo(406.00316,421.83343 ,442.19716,458.07143 ,444.89016,482.76843 );
               path.curveTo(431.76716,528.31343 ,393.39116,574.56743 ,350.22516,594.56743 );
               path.curveTo(316.63916,610.12643 ,278.88716,614.34043 ,242.18316,610.35243 );
               path.curveTo(232.12112,609.27843 ,228.38012,619.29143 ,238.47016,621.92243 );
               path.curveTo(274.01216,631.28543 ,320.32416,637.73643 ,356.57416,628.91043 );
               path.curveTo(420.03416,613.46343 ,456.48216,533.71643 ,457.61616,470.82943);  

               path.closePath();
               g2d.draw(path);
               g2d.fill(path);
}       
}
```

Thanks anyways